# How can I use "nullptr" for null pointers prior to C23?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, c23

In C23, the [`nullptr` keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/nullptr) got standardized. I would prefer to use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` prior to C23 too because it means that I could write code which compiles in:

- C, prior to C23
- C, since C23
- C++

I could simply use `NULL` in both languages and every C standard, but that would be highly unusual in C++ code, and `nullptr` is becoming the norm in both languages anyway.

As far as I know, you are not allowed to use `#define` to replace keywords in the language, and that may cause problems when defining a compatibility macro. Basically, I need:

```cpp
// only if this is neither C++ nor C23
#define nullptr /* something */
```

How can I properly define this macro?

Comment: Have you tried #ifndef?

Comment: @stark I'd expect the concern here is it's not a `#define` but a new keyword.

Comment: There's no way to comparatively `define` `nullptr` because `nullptr` is a keyword, not a value, right?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with `0`; this `nullptr` only confuses the issue, especially hidden behind a macro.

Comment: @Neil `0` or `NULL` wouldn't be very idiomatic in C++. They may also bypass constructors that are meant to catch mistakes, like `std::string(std::nullptr_t)`. Now that `nullptr` is a keyword in both languages, I think it should be the default, and used in all code. The question is just how to define a fallback macro for C/C++ versions where it's not a keyword yet.

Comment: I think allowing `C` and `C++` to diverge should have happened years ago, but the decisions of standard committees aside, still a very valid question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some things of note:

- `__STDC__` and `__STDC_VERSION__` were added in "C95" (the addendum to ISO C 9899:1990).
- You cannot check for `nullptr` using pre-processor conditionals because it is not a macro.
- The user might forget to include `stddef.h` or equivalent header even when using a conforming C23 compiler so don't assume that this one is #included.
- Current versions of gcc and clang support `-std=c2x` which does contain `nullptr` but sets `__STDC_VERSION__` to a placeholder value 202000L.
- Not all versions of C++ contain `nullptr` since it was added in C++11.

Therefore the macro checks should look something like this:

```
/* C++11 or later? */
#if (defined(__cplusplus) && __cplusplus >= 201103L)  
  #include <cstddef>

/* C2x/C23 or later? */
#elif ( defined(__STDC__) &&          \
        defined(__STDC_VERSION__) &&  \
        (__STDC_VERSION__ >= 202000L) )
  #include <stddef.h> /* nullptr_t */

/* pre C23, pre C++11 or non-standard */
#else
  #define nullptr (void*)0
  typedef void* nullptr_t;

#endif
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend avoiding `NULL`, and instead using an explicit `((void*)0)`. A conforming C implementation could define `NULL` such that it expands to an integer (which, of course, does not preclude the expansion from being a null pointer constant).  Else you might have the confusing situation where the type of `nullptr` is different from `nullptr_t`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger `NULL` is guaranteed to be a _null pointer constant_, which in turn means either `(void*)0` or `0`. `NULL` cannot be anything else but those two. (6.3.2.3 §3 and 7.19) Not to be confused with the representation of a _null pointer_, which is what you get if you assign a null pointer constant to a pointer. During that assignment, the compiler is free to give the pointer any implementation-defined value including non-zero values.

Comment: More or less, @Lundin.  `NULL` can be *any* integer constant expression with value 0.  But perhaps I was unclear.  I thought it would be understood that I was not recommending avoiding `NULL` *in general*, but only to avoid using it to define `nullptr`. If the implementation opts for the integer constant expression option then `NULL` has type `int` (notwithstanding that it is a null pointer constant).  If you then use that define `nullptr`, and also define `nullptr_t` as `void *`, then the type of `nullptr` is different from `nullptr_t`. Don't you think that's undesirable?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah if you are doing this for the purpose of avoiding `0` and not just for compatibility reasons. I guess an integer constant expression would be undesirable in cases like `_Generic(x, int: foo(), nullptr_t: bar());`

Comment: Yes, that's a specific case that could cause *bona fide* issue.  More generally, those versions of C and C++ that provide `nullptr` and `nullptr_t` all specify that the latter is the type of the former, and code aiming at those versions is entitled to rely on that.  The OP is looking for compatibility, so needlessly breaking that type relationship is counterproductive for them.

Comment: clang actually protests against `(nullptr_t){0}` in C23 mode. Fun little example: https://godbolt.org/z/j6YKx8osq. Won't compile with clang in strict mode.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ok so you convinced me :) I updated the code to use `(void*)0` instead.

Comment: As for Clang, I think it's very reasonable in this respect.  The spec says "No type other than `nullptr_t` shall be converted to `nullptr_t`" (C23 6.5.4/4).  The fact that `0` is a null pointer constant does not get around that.  In fact, you can't convert `(void *)0` to `nullptr_t`, either, unless by leveraging an extension.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Makes me wonder how the compiler is supposed to behave if you union type pun a pointer with a given value into a `nullptr_t`. Probably a lot of strange corner cases that the ISO WG didn't quite forsee :)

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to detect whether you're using C23 through [predefined macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace#Predefined_macros):

```c
/* bad, don't do this */
#if !__cplusplus && __STDC_VERSION__ <= 201710
    #define nullptr ((void*)0)
#endif
```

However, such a simple macro can trigger compiler warnings (`clang -Wundef -std=c89`):

```
<source>:1:6: warning: '__cplusplus' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
    1 | #if !__cplusplus && __STDC_VERSION__ <= 201710
      |      ^
<source>:1:21: warning: '__STDC_VERSION__' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
    1 | #if !__cplusplus && __STDC_VERSION__ <= 201710
      |
```

The solution can be rewritten so no warnings are triggered:

```c
/* don't do anything in C++, or if someone else defined a compatibility macro */
#if !defined(__cplusplus) && !defined(nullptr) && \
   (!defined(__STDC_VERSION__) || __STDC_VERSION__ <= 201710)
    /* -Wundef is avoided by using short circuiting in the condition */
    #define nullptr ((void*)0)
#endif
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/e64Mj1Mqx)*

Comment: You can also use
`#if !defined(__STDC_VERSION__) || __STDC_VERSION__ < 202311L` which doesn't trigger warnings either.

Comment: `#if !__cplusplus` is always naive and dangerous, should be `#if !defined(__cplusplus)`. Otherwise a macro which is not defined evaluates to 0 and `!0` gives 1.

Comment: @Lundin, ...which works as intended. Not sure what your point is.

Comment: And `nullptr` is not a macro but a predefined constant.

Comment: @ikegami Well to begin with not all versions of C++ support nullptr.

Comment: @Lundin Switching to `!defined(__cplusplus)` is not going to help that. Not sure what your point here is either.

Comment: @ikegami No. `nullptr` is not a macro so it cannot get passed to `defined`.

Comment: Thanks @NateEldredge, that makes the solution a bit shorter; I've updated the answer.

Comment: Also as of today both gcc and clang support nullptr_t but they do not support `__STDC_VERSION__ == 202311L` because that constant is set to `202000L` when compilding with -std=c2x.

Comment: You might also want to conditionally define the type `nullptr_t` which is the type of `nullptr`. For C23 it gets defined by `#include <stddef.h>` as `typedef typeof_unqual(nullptr) nullptr_t;` but you'd probably want `typedef void *nullptr_t;` for earlier versions.

Comment: To spell it out, `defined(nullptr)` is always 0 on all compilers made to this date and will still be 0 when C23 is released.

Comment: @Lundin good point; I've made it detect whether it's C17 or lower instead.

Comment: @Lundin my concern is that someone else could have had the same bright idea in C17 or lower, and they would have defined `nullptr` themselves. In that case, `#define` would overwrite an existing macro and give you a warning.

Comment: @IanAbbott I'm not sure if that's a good idea. `nullptr_t` is intended to be unique type, and this property could be relied upon in generic selection etc.. If someone defined it as a non-unique type, it could break stuff. The best solution is probably not to use `nullptr_t` prior to C23 at all, to ensure compatibility.

Comment: Why `#define nullptr ((void*)0)` instead of `#define nullptr NULL`?

Comment: @adabsurdum `NULL` could have integer type in C.

Comment: @JanSchultke Good point! I neglected the part about `nullptr_t` needing to be a unique pointer type.

Comment: @adabsurdum because I don't want to assume that the user included `<stddef.h>` or some other header which includes `NULL`. I also don't want to include such a header if it's not really necessary.

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I know you are not allowed to use #define to replace keywords in the language, and that may cause problems when defining a compatibility macro.

Mostly true (C23 6.4.2.1/6).  There is an explicit exception for keywords whose names begin with a double-underscore or with an underscore and a capital letter. (C23 6.4.2.1/7, as clarified by footnote 80)

Although "not allowed" is not how I would describe it, at least for C.  The language spec does not forbid defining a macro whose identifier matches a language keyword of any form.  But, subject to the exception described above, it will interpret language keywords *as* keywords, which are not subject to macro replacement, rather than as identifiers.

> I would prefer to use nullptr instead of NULL prior to C23 too because it means that I could write code which compiles in [C++ and all versions of standard C].

This is a noble goal, and, speaking from (pre-C23) experience, a true PITA.  The shared subset of C and C++ is large enough to program in, but it is not particularly comfortable.  I would suggest that you choose *one* language to write in, and support the other via binary compatibility instead of source compatibility.

But if you insist, then [your other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76899758/2402272) shows how you can use language version macros to inform conditional compilation directives, so as to make appropriate decisions about whether to define a `nullptr` macro.

**On the other hand**, as I already covered, it is allowed in C to define a macro with the same name as a keyword -- it is just *ineffective*.  So you could consider just defining `nullptr` as a macro unconditionally, or at least for all versions of C.  A C23 compiler might be moved to warn about that, but a conforming one should accept it.